# How to exclude maven plugin configuration (unrecognized parameter -encoding)

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I am using `jaxws-maven-plugin` to generate some JAX-WS clients based on WSDL files.

I need to use JDK 1.6 so I am executing with JAX-WS Tools 2.1.7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If I use recent versions of `jaxws-maven-plugin` `2.2.1` or `2.3` over the 2.1.7 jaxws-tools my build doesn't work because an invalid -encoding parameter is added to the command line.

```
unrecognized parameter -encoding
```

Full command is

```
[DEBUG] cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe" -Xbootclasspath/p:.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.1\jaxb-api-2.1.jar;.m2\repository\javax\xml\soap\saaj-api\1.3\saaj-api-1.3.jar;.m2\repository\javax\xml\ws\jaxws-api\2.1\jaxws-api-2.1.jar org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.Invoker com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool -keep -s <some dir> -d <some dir> -encoding UTF-8 -p <some package> file:<some wsdl file>"
```

The following pom.xml is working fine, I use 2.2 which does not send the encoding parameter.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version> <!-- This version works fine -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>ConsultarStatusNfe.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <!-- for JDK 6 compilation compatibility -->
                <xnocompile>false</xnocompile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the latest versions by setting the `<target>2.1</target>` configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase/>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
        <sourceDestDir>src/main/generated</sourceDestDir>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>myfile.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <packageName>com.souzacruz.pwnfeintegrator</packageName>
        <!-- for JDK 6 compilation compatibility -->
        <xnocompile>false</xnocompile>
        <target>2.1</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

the version 2.1.1 of the plug in jaxws-tools does not support the parameter "-encoding". Use a later version, for example 2.2.6 that it does.